# Angular function call not working in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I recently started working on UI. So I am using angularjs with html. I have one doubt regarding Internet Explorer css styling. I am using a angular call to decide a background color of a div based on a field value. It is working fine in chrome and firefox. But in IE it is giving some error as below

[image]

[image]

This is my HTML code

```
<div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid black; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px; clear: both; background-color: {{get_color(system.status)}}; position: relative">
```

This is my angular function

```
$scope.get_color = function(val){

    if (val == '0'){    
        return 'rgb(245,215,215)';
    }
    else{
        return 'rgba(211,211,211,0)';
    }
}
```

Any Idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `background-color` is set to an Angular expression of `{{get_color(system.status)}` but it should be `{{get_color(system.status)}}`.  Notice the missing `}` at the end.

Try changing your HTML to this:

```
<div class="row" ng-style="get_color(system.status)" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-top: 1px solid black; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;margin-right:5px;margin-left:5px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px; clear: both; position: relative">
```

And in your `get_color` function, do something like this:

```
$scope.get_color = function(val){
    if (val == '0'){    
        return { "background-color": 'rgb(245,215,215)' };
    }
    else{
        return { "background-color": 'rgb(211,211,211,0)' };
    }
}
```

To summarize, use `ng-style` and have your function return an object containing the style(s) you want to use.

Comment: I have added my html code. Please check and I have two curly brackets at the end and I don't have any idea why it is missing while rendering in the browser. I did not notice that till now. And the same code is working fine in other browsers like chrome and firefox where it is rendering the second curly brace also

Comment: How should the html be like?? And I have added my angular function. What change should I have to do?

Comment: sorry, the HTML was hidden... check it again.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks :) But what is the reason that it didn't work when I used like I mentioned?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea.  That's a weird problem that I've never heard of before.  Luckily, with Angular there's usually always another way to do something.